# Problem with overriding Laravel MessageBag

Tags: laravel

My goal:
We ar developing an API and we need to customize error message not only to send custom string, but also to send cusotm code.
E.g.: custom invalid email error message should look like this:

```
error[
 'code' => 102,
 'message' => 'invalid email'
]
```

I could set these custom error messages, to be arrays, but I have a problem with emails.

I get: 
"Array to string conversion" at Illuminate\Support\MessageBag at line 248.
The reason of it, is because it is expecting a string and now I have an array.

```
  protected function transform($messages, $format, $messageKey)
    {
        return collect((array) $messages)
            ->map(function ($message) use ($format, $messageKey) {
                // We will simply spin through the given messages and transform each one
                // replacing the :message place holder with the real message allowing
                // the messages to be easily formatted to each developer's desires.
                return str_replace([':message', ':key'], [$message, $messageKey], $format);
            })->all();
    }
```

I would like to override (bind) this method with:

```
  protected function transform($messages, $format, $messageKey)
    {
        return collect((array) $messages)
            ->map(function ($message) use ($format, $messageKey) {
                if(is_array($message)){
                    $message = json_encode($message);
                }
                // We will simply spin through the given messages and transform each one
                // replacing the :message place holder with the real message allowing
                // the messages to be easily formatted to each developer's desires.
                return str_replace([':message', ':key'], [$message, $messageKey], $format);
            })->all();
    }
```

I have daone the following steps.
I have created Libraries/Extensions/MessagesBag folder and plced the followint files there.

MessageBagServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Libraries\Extensions\MessageBag;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class MessageBagServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Illuminate\Support\MessageBag', 'App\Libraries\Extensions\MessageBag\YcoMessageBag');
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return array('messagebag');
    }
}
```

MessageBagFacade.php

```
namespace App\Libraries\Extensions\MessageBag;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade as IlluminateFacade;
class MessageBagFacade extends IlluminateFacade {

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'messagebag'; }

}
```

YcoMessagebag.php

```
namespace App\Libraries\Extensions\MessageBag;

use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag as OriginalMessageBag;

class YcoMessageBag extends OriginalMessageBag{
    /**
     * Format an array of messages.
     *
     * @param  array   $messages
     * @param  string  $format
     * @param  string  $messageKey
     * @return array
     */
    protected function transform($messages, $format, $messageKey)
    {
        return collect((array) $messages)
            ->map(function ($message) use ($format, $messageKey) {
                if(is_array($message)){
                    $message = json_encode($message);
                }
                // We will simply spin through the given messages and transform each one
                // replacing the :message place holder with the real message allowing
                // the messages to be easily formatted to each developer's desires.
                return str_replace([':message', ':key'], [$message, $messageKey], $format);
            })->all();
    }
}
```

I have registered my MessageBagServiceprodider.php in config/app.php

```
  App\Libraries\Extensions\MessageBag\MessageBagServiceProvider::class,
```

When I have died and dumped in MessageBagServiceProvider's register method, it worked, the code died and dumped "hello".

But the MessageBag class is not overriding, still the original class is loaded.
I have tried to play with

```
$this->app->bind('Illuminate\Support\MessageBag', 'App\Libraries\Extensions\MessageBag\YcoMessageBag');
```

I have tried with: $this->app->singleton, 
I have tried to reach the original class with \Illuminate\Support\MessageBag also tried with '\App\Libraries\Extensions\MessageBag\YcoMessageBag', but no success.
Can I override this class? What can be the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: That class isn't being resolved from the container. The places that need `MessageBag`s, like the Validator, call `new MessageBag`, so there is no interaction with the container to resolve that.

Comment: @lagbox Thank you, now it makes sense. I thought that I can override any core class like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, here is my solution:
I have created Exteptions/Handler.php

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
 /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Exception $e
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {

        if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
            return $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($exception, $request);
        } elseif ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            $modelName = strtolower(class_basename($exception->getModel()));

            return $this->errorResponse(
                'Does not exists any ' . $modelName . ' with this id',
                Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND
            );
        } elseif ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            return $this->unauthenticated($request, $exception);
        } elseif ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
            return $this->errorResponse($exception->getMessage(), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
        } elseif ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
            return $this->errorResponse('The specified request is invalid!', Response::HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        } elseif ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            return $this->errorResponse('The specified url cannot be found!', Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        } elseif ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
            $message = $exception->getMessage();
            $status = $exception->getStatusCode();

            $httpStatusCodes = collect(Response::$statusTexts);

            if (!$httpStatusCodes->has($status)) {
                $status = Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY;
            }

            if ($message == "") {
                $message = "An error occured when processing request!";
            }

            return $this->errorResponse($message, $status);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);

    }
  /**
     * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $exception
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return $this->errorResponse('Unauthenticated', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }


    /**
     * Create a response object from the given validation exception.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function convertValidationExceptionToResponse(ValidationException $e, $request)
    {
        $errors = $e->validator->errors()->getMessages();
        $errors = $this->convertValidationErrors($errors);

        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'error' => $errors,
            'status' => 422,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ], 422);

    }

    protected function convertValidationErrors($errors){
        $codes = [
            101 => [
                'code'=> 101,
                'message'=> 'A mező kitöltése kötelező'
            ],
           106=>[
               'code'=> 106,
               'message'=> 'A mező tartalma nem elég hosszú'
           ],
            102 =>[
                'code'=> 102,
                'message'=> 'A mező tartalma nem elég hosszú'
            ],
            103 => [
                'code'=> 103,
                'message'=> 'A mező tartalma túl hosszú'
            ],
            105 => [
                'code'=> 105,
                'message'=> ' A mező tartalma nem szöveg'
            ],
            107 => [
                'code'=> 107,
                'message'=> 'Formátum nem megfelelő'
            ],
            104 => [
                'code'=> 104,
                'message'=> 'Az email formátuma nem megfelelő'
            ],
        ];


        foreach($errors as $key => $code){

            if(isset($codes[$code[0]])) {
                unset($errors[$key][0]);
                $errors[$key]['code'] = $codes[$code[0]]['code'];
                if(env('APP_ENV') != 'local') {
                    $errors[$key]['message'] = $codes[$code[0]]['message'];
                }
            }
        }
        return $errors;
    }

}
```

Maybe not the most beautiful solution, but it works.